# Random function on each time page load

Tags: javascript, function, random

I have some functions:

```
fbFetch();
fbFetch1();
fbFetch2();
fbFetch3();
fbFetch4();
```

I want to trigger a random function on page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fns = [fbFetch, fbFetch2, fbFetch /* ...you get the idea */]
var selectedFn = Math.floor(Math.random() * fns.length);
body.addEventListener("load", fns[selectedFn], false);
```

Comment: `(fns.length - 0.1)` if ever `Math.random()` returned `1`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Math.random never returns 1. Read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: thanks for the information. I thought it included `0` and `1`. I'll fix my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Push the functions into an array then call one of them using a random index:

```
var a = [];
a.push(fbFetch);
a.push(fbFetch1);
//...

var index = parseInt(Math.random() * a.length);
a[index]();
```

Comment: They have the same result. Just the first thing that come across my mind is use `parseInt`

Comment: Math.random never returns 1. See my comment under my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put functions inside array and fire it with math random.

```
var arr = ['fbFetch();','fbFetch1();','fbFetch2();','fbFetch3();','fbFetch4();'];
var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

$(document).ready(arr[ran]());
```